# Query output differs in different queries

Tags: google-bigquery

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(bigquery|big query|google cloud)') 
-- Query result - 7669
```

But If we do individually, like below, I get a different count:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(bigquery)') 
-- 1560
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(big query)') 
-- 127
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM `bigquery-public-data.hacker_news.full` 
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(google cloud)') 
-- 6222
```

`Total = 7909`, but if we query together we are getting  `7669` .

If I am making a mistake somewhere, please correct me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this query:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 'abc' text) 

SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM data
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(a|b|c)')
```

The result is 1.

And if I try:

```
WITH data AS (SELECT 'abc' text) 

SELECT COUNT(*) c
FROM data
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(a)')
```

Same if I try with just 'a', just 'b', or just 'c'. If each gives me 1, why don't I get 3 as a result when I query for the `REGEXP_CONTAINS(text, '(?i)(a|b|c)')`?

Because one text might contain multiple of the substrings you're looking for, thus counting as one.